# Linux driver for PCI device not hot plugging

Tags: hardware, linux-device-driver

I am writing a Linux PCI driver for a PCIe device that must be *hot pluggable*.

The device attaches via cable to a PCIe redriver card that fits into a PCIe slot.

When the device is plugged in at boot time, I can find it with `lspci`, and the driver probes successfully. However, if the cable is unplugged during run time, `lspci` still shows the device as present, and the driver's PCI `remove` method is not called, even after echoing '1' to `/sys/bus/pci/rescan`.

This problem reverses itself if the device is not plugged in at boot time: it will not be showed with `lspci`, even after the cable is connected, and the `probe` method won't get called.

My module uses the `pci_register_driver()` and `pci_unregister_driver()` library; the driver uses only the `probe` and `remove` methods (no `suspend` or `resume`), and `id_table` initializes the `vendor id` and `device id`.

Are there functions in the Linux Kernel that need to be called to register a PCI device for *hot plugging*?

Comment: I think your driver does not follow the PCI hotplug device driver model. But I am not familiar with the PCI hotplug device driver model either. You can take a look at example codes ./driver/pci/hotplug/pcihp_skeleton.c, and some other codes under directory ./driver/pci/hotplug.

Comment: Thanks, tian_yufeng, that looks like the right direction to take. Unfortunately, pcihp_skeleton.c and the documentation for pci/hotplug both look to be out of date (pci_hp_register() in particular has changed), so it's going to be a deep-sea dive into the Kernel source code for a while.